# how can I resize the screen in React html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need your help.
I started recently web development, and i heard somethings about grid, but i do not understand.
I use react jsx for documents.

Image of below, I want to when screen lg, It will show 4 of them.
Also I want to carry logout button to right side of the nav bar.
[image]

space evenly and display:flex is not working, i want like row, not column:
[image]

my note css code:
.note {

```
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
  float: left;
  
}
```

my nav bar css codes:

```
.hero nav {
  background-color: #0ca486;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.hero nav button {
  width: 86px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background: #3a2b58;
}
```

my logout button code in jsx:

```
<nav>
            <h1>ASD</h1>
            <button onClick={handleLogOut}>Logout</button>
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
```

I solved like this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to web dev, I highly recommend you to read through this docs about flex and grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

They are super easy to follow and would make your life easier!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `display:flex; justify-content:space-between` in navbar css

And in note's use `display:flex; justify-content:space-evenly`

Comment: navbar is okey, but note section, its not working. It's like Column, but i want row. I also added space-evenly image in above

Comment: Try `justify-content:space-between; flex-direction: row;`. If it doesn't work, than maybe width is too large to display it in rows.

Answer (score 0):

For aligning the Logout button to right side add :
`position: absolute; right: 50px;`

To align your note you can use CSS as :
`display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;`

Or

You can use Material-Ui lib with React to manage it using Grid : [Grid documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)

Comment: navbar is okey, but note section, its not working. It's like Column, but i want row. I also added 'space-evenly and flex' image in above